# How to install Mac OS on Quicksilver PowerDesk G4 with blank hard drive

Tags: macos, installation, boot, boot-camp, firmware

I have a Quicksilver PowerDesk G4 and the hard drive is blank and also I have no boot disc.

What should I do then? Would burning a Mac OS 9.2.1 installion disc using a Mac computer and the IS960 format work? The image is currently a DMG image.

I first need to extract the contents of the installation disc image on a Mac and then burn the folders / contents to a DVD-R disc?

I would then turn the Mac on and try to boot off a CD, holding down the C key. If this fails I would boot in open firmware so I can load the installer.  Are these the correct steps?

Are there any additional measures I have to take? What do I need to do with the hard drive besides just formatting it as HFS+?

I been doing a lot of research, but support for this OS has been discontinued.  I can only go up to Mac OS X 10.4 as the highest version.

Also, do I need to first fix the firmware if I'm getting errors such as "default catch x0000-something and stack overflow / load size too small " when I try to do operations in the firmware?

I do have a successful connection if I browse for the computer on my network. I do see the MAC address and the IP address. So would a network boot / setting up Mac OS over a network be easier when I run into problems trying to load the installer from CD or an external device?

The specs are:

- EMC#1896
- PMG4 800MHZ/256MD SDRAM/40GB DVDRW/CDRW/RV200
- 56k MDM/GIGE
- Assembled: 2001

Comment: Having a hard time understanding your question. You're making so many assumptions… can't you just give everything a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That machine can run OS X 10.4.11 if you upgrade the RAM so I would strongly suggest skipping OS 9 altogether. To run 10.4 you need at least 256 MB of RAM but more is highly recommended.  That machine can take up to 1.5 GB.

After adding the RAM get yourself a retail DVD of 10.4 and boot with it by holding the C key or Option key.  Make sure you do not use a grey system disk that came with another machine, you must use the regular retail installer DVD.

If you have access to another machine running 10.4 you can clone an image of it to an external firewire drive and use that to restore the clone.  To make the clone you would use disk utility on the running 10.4 system, format it as Apple Partition Map scheme, then clone the internal HDD to the external drive. Then you can boot from the external drive on the G4 with the option key held down and use disk utility to restore the external drive to the internal HDD.

The above procedure can also be used to clone an installer disk to the external drive.  The key point to making it bootable is to ensure you use Apple Partition Map when formatting it, and it must be a firewire drive.  The older Macs will not boot via USB.

Comment: can you explain this more, I have 1.5 in memory.  Can i burn an Install 10.4 disk.  If i know someone who has a MAC Os  x 10.4 can i can burn a copy of my fiend's os 10.4 install disc that for myself and use that to install the mac by booting from it.  BUt since that uses a dual layer dvd.  I need to use then a external hard drive. Would this be possible? or what files can I remove from the OS install disc to make it fit on an DVD-4.7g and successfully boot and install also.